# Can Chrome developer window overwrite the css rules at the sametime?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, sdk, ide

Currently I am using browser 's developer mode to test whether the element is at the right position, However , I find that it takes sometime whenever I need to change .Everytime I need to test on browser and go to the corresponding css file to edit it . So , I am wondering are there any way to directly edit the css file in chrome developer mode? Thanks a lot

Comment: You could try googling "edit css file in chrome dev tools". Did you? Then again, you could also try googling "change my Stack Overflow user name". Anyway, another alternative is http://addyosmani.com/blog/autosave-changes-chrome-dev-tools/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Live CSS Editor Chrome extension can do that for you:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/live-css-editor/oelggcmknbjmhkpgjfhakedcfnkgbdpg?hl=en